# How can someone ask a question with a bounty that is worth more reputation than their own reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

While browsing the Windows Phone 8 questions today, I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886505/how-to-send-message-via-sip-server-by-boghe-in-windows-phone) question. This is a question with an open bounty of +200 rep. However, the user who posted it and opened the bounty has 23 rep. How is this even possible ?

Comment: From [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty): "All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The bounty amount is subtracted **when you set the bounty**. The user *had* 223 rep, then set the bounty.

A bounty is the price you pay to have your question promoted, so it is paid *up front*. The system may then award this prize to the best answer given (with the help of the bounty setter). It is not a sum paid for getting an answer.